# make plumber's putty soft

Tags: plumbing, putty

I have some amount of putty which has dried, it isn't old though. Is it possible to make it soft as clay again? Normally how long can a putty last when open?

Comment: Plumber's putty isn't solvent-based as it's not intended to dry or cure. Try some mineral oil in small quantities, and knead it in your hands to warm it. That said, there are fewer recommended uses for it every year. Most fixtures are gasket-sealed these days.

Comment: @isherwood, thanks for comment. What is the lowest temperature the putty is allowed to be stored at without being dried? Are there any recommendations for this?

Comment: @isherwood, I mean at what temperature the plumber's putty can be stored once opened?

Answer (score -2):

I’ve had mine for about 2 1/2 years and still seems playable. The manufacturer of my “wood filler” makes a “Thinner” which they claim “Restores solvent based wood fillers to their original consistency.”

BTW, where I live there’s an ‘ol finish carpenter that we all admire how close his filler in the nail holes match the stain of the wood. A few years ago I stuck around on a job and watched him work. After he cut the trim boards, he saved the sawdust and mixed it in the wood putty. Clever.  Now, I think, there is putty that can be stained to match wood.

Comment: Plumbers putty is not wood putty.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Oops...I miss read that one...